# activate an if/else statement if functions are activated in the right order (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I solved this myself by creating a variable that changes in each function. This var is set to a letter in function a() and if it is that letter when I click on function c() then it changes into another letter and so on. Lastly I have a if statement that activates if it
is the right last letter.

I have a project where I have several functions and I want another function to activate if the first 4 functions is activated in a particular order. (and then I want several else if statements to get different functions to activate for other orders, but that I can figure out myself)

I don't know how to get javascript acknowledge that a chain of functions are activated in the right order. (if that is even possible)

as an example:
I have function a(), function b(), function c() and function d().

if they are activated in order acbd I want function s() to activate.
and if they are activated in order bdca I want function f() to activate.

Comment: Can you put some code you're currently working on..?? You can use callbacks to chain the functions

Comment: [Function currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)

Comment: This is an example where putting some code will be more descriptive than just text. If you are taking about asynchronous functions you can have callbacks or async/await pattern

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.